# Display text in stack-mode next to an icon in a Flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a comment icon that I want to display the number of comments and the word "Comments" next to it.

But the word "Comments" should be displayed under the number and not next to it.

Similar to this

[image]

So far the text is being displayed next to each other.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/halnex/d5sft5pt/9/

HTML

```
<div class="post-meta-alt">
  <div class="social-share-top">
    <span class="social-share-top-text">Share</span>
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook">
      <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter">
      <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google">
      <span class="fa fa-google"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-pinterest">
      <span class="fa fa-pinterest"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="comments-top">
    <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-pinterest">
      <span class="fa fa-comment"></span>
    </a>
    <p>78</p>
    <p>Comments</p>
  </div>
  <div class="author-top">
    author name
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.post-meta-alt {
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
.post-meta-alt span.social-share-top-text {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.post-meta-alt .comments-top,
.post-meta-alt .author-top {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

**PS:** Is this the correct way of doing it with Bootstrap? Using Flexbox or is there a better conventional way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the paragraphs in a div:

```
<div class="coment">
      <p>78</p>
      <p>Comments</p>
 </div>
```

And add style to organize them

```
.coment p {
  margin: 3px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

**[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5sft5pt/10/)**